# res.status() vs. res.statusCode

Tags: node.js, express, response, status

I would like to know if these two different approach is it identical in expressjs?

```
 res.statusCode = 500;
 return res.json({
  status: "error"
 });
```

or

```
return res.status(500).json({
  status: "error"
});
```

Comment: And `res` is...?

Comment: response inside a route for example.

Comment: [`res` represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends when it gets an HTTP request.](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res)

Comment: @Wauwau what route? You only mention nodejs, so you mean the `res` of an expressjs route?

Comment: @pzaenger Is to teach Wauwau how to explain questions better. Is a must.

Comment: yes exactly, sorry I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[expressjs - Response](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res)

> the `res` object is an enhanced version of Node’s own response object and supports all [built-in fields and methods](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).

[res.status(code)](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.status)

> Sets the HTTP status for the response. It is a chainable alias of Node’s [response.statusCode](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_statuscode).

So the result is the same. expressjs just added a chainable version of `statusCode`.

Comment: @Wauwau the callback of a router/middleware has most of the time the signature `function(req, res)` or `function(req, res, next)`, but you are free to name the paramets how ever you want `function(req, resToClient, next)`. The second parameter will always hold a [http.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) that is extended by expressjs with additional functionality.

Comment: Once you've set it via `res.status(code)`, you can retrieve it later via `res.statusCode`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the actual implementation of the `res.status` function and it eventually sets the `statusCode`. But `res.status` performs additional checking before setting the `statusCode`.

Both are identical in terms of what they achieve, but `res.status` is more preferrable.

```js
res.status = function status(code) {
  if ((typeof code === 'string' || Math.floor(code) !== code) && code > 99 && code < 1000) {
    deprecate('res.status(' + JSON.stringify(code) + '): use res.status(' + Math.floor(code) + ') instead')
  }
  this.statusCode = code;
  return this;
};
```

Answer (score -6):

Multiple status codes like status code 200, 404, and 500 in the same code? 200 for success, 404 for no data matching.

Comment: Question is asking about two different approaches/features : `res.statusCode` and `res.status`

Comment: Hey my friend, your answer makes no sense as the question is not asking about the meaning of HTTP status code. Read the question carefully before answering it.

Comment: This reads more like a comment. Perhaps Sachdeva was trying to solicit clarification on why a chainable alias is necessary.